# Narrow elements in a join table by a dropdown menu. (Rails 4)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

for one of my join tables, I'd like to filter results based on a dropdown menu selection. Before I explain further, I will provide the relevant code.

**I have 3 models in question:**

```
class Scoreboard 
  has_many :teams, has_many :team_matches
end

class Team
  belongs_to Scoreboard

  #self reference with the teams to create team_matches. 
  has_many :first_team, class_name: "TeamMatch", foreign_key: "team_a_id", dependent: :destroy 
  has_many :team_a, through: :first_team, source: :team_a

  has_many :second_team, class_name: "TeamMatch", foreign_key: "team_b_id", dependent: :destroy 
  has_many :team_b, through: :second_teams, source: :team_b
end
```

**And the final Model which is a join table of teams:**

```
class Team_Match 
    belongs_to :team_a, class_name: "Team"
    belongs_to :team_b, class_name: "Team"
    belongs_to :scoreboard 
end
```

**Team Matches Controller Code for the Index View:**

```
class TeamMatchesController < ApplicationController
    require 'will_paginate/array'

    def index
        @selected = true
        @scoreboard = Scoreboard.find(params[:scoreboard_id])
        @teams = @scoreboard.teams
        @matches = @scoreboard.team_matches.order("match_date DESC").paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5)
    end
end
```

**The Index Page View:**

```
<h2 class="team-matches-header">TEAM MATCHES</h2>

<% if manager_or_owner?(@scoreboard, current_user) %> 
   <%= link_to "Add Matches", new_scoreboard_team_match_path(@scoreboard), class: "btn btn-primary" %>

   <%= link_to "Clear Matches", deletematches_scoreboard_path(@scoreboard),method: :delete, class: "btn btn-danger", :data => {:confirm => "Are you absolutely sure you want to delete all matches?"} %>
<% end %>

<%= form_tag(scoreboard_team_matches_path, :method => "get", id: "match-search-form", autocomplete: "off") do %>
   <div class="row new-member-field">
       <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
           <%= select_tag "teams", options_from_collection_for_select(@teams, "id", "name"), prompt: "Select something", class:"form-control" %>
           <%= submit_tag 'Filter' %>
       </div>
   </div>
<% end %>

<div class="match-list">
   <%= render 'match_list' %>
</div>
```

**The Match List Partial**

```
 <% if @matches.present? %>
    <% @matches.each do |game| %>
        <div class="row match-div clearfix" id="match_<%= game.id %>">
               <div class="col-xs-12 match-column">   
                        <div class="facing-teams">
                            <div class="first-team">
                               <%= game.team_a.name %>
                            </div>
                            <div class="second-team">
                                <%= game.team_b.name %>
                            </div>
                       </div>
               </div>
         </div>
    <% end %>
<% end %> 



<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 new-member-pages">
        <%= will_paginate @matches %>
    </div>
</div>
```

So far on the team matches index page, I have been able to put a dropdown menu selection with a list of teams. The trouble I'm having is how to make it functional. Upon submission of a team from the dropdown selection, I would like to display a list of Match objects(@matches) whose `:team_a_id` or `:team_b_id` matches the selected Team's id. How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [scopes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes) to achieve what you want.  Scopes are reusable filters that you can apply to an association to find exactly the records that you want.

This is how you would create a scope that finds the matches for a particular team:

```rb
class Team_Match
  scope :has_team, ->(team_id) {
    team_a = arel_table[:team_a_id].eq(team_id)
    team_b = arel_table[:team_b_id].eq(team_id)
    team_a_or_b = team_a.or(team_b)

    where(team_a_or_b)
  }
end
```

This uses arel (which ActiveRecord uses under the hood to create SQL queries) in order to find a match in either the `team_a_id` or `team_b_id` columns.  If you have no idea what's going on with the above code, take a quick trip to [Mastering AR and Arel](http://danshultz.github.io/talks/mastering_activerecord_arel/#/) to get up to speed.

You use the scope like this:

```
matches = Team_Match.has_team(team_id)
```

You can also use the scope on any relationship that joins to `Team_Match`:

```
matches = @scoreboard.team_matches.has_team(team_id)
```

Scopes can also be chained together:

```
matches = @scoreboard.team_matches.has_team(team_id).where(match_date: today)
```

The scope allows you to pass in the team id from the select box to find the matches:

```rb
def index
  @selected = true
  @scoreboard = Scoreboard.find(params[:scoreboard_id])
  @teams = @scoreboard.teams
  @matches = @scoreboard.team_matches.order("match_date DESC")
  @matches = @matches.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5)

  # we apply the scope (if present) to only show the matches for the selected team
  if (team_id = params[:selected_team_id])
    @matches = @matches.has_team(team_id)
  end

end
```

The only change you would need to make to the above code is working out what the actual name is of the param variable that holds the selected team id.

Comment: This is awesome. Thanks.